# non-blocking code with while loops

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, websocket, pthreads

I'm trying to write some code that will spawn off two separate chunks of code listening for connections.

```
int runsocket()
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    pthread_t thread_id;


    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &client_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( thread_id , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];

    //Send some messages to the client
    message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    message = "Now type something and i shall repeat what you type \n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //end of string marker
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';

        //Send the message back to client
        write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));

        //clear the message buffer
        memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, say theoretically, I have a runsocket2() that also opens a socket on a separate port, using a separate connection_handler function. In my main, I call runsocket(); and runsocket2() . Only run socket(); gets executed and it freezes from that point forward, with runsocket2(); never being called. How can I get around this and effectively execute both of them?

The real issue I'm encountering is using a websocket library, that has a call:     libwebsock_wait(ctx);

Once this is called, that's it - all code below it no longer gets executed, as it essentially creates a loop. I'd like to be able to force a separate socket to listen on a separate port and process data through it outside of the websocket. If I call runsocket(); prior to libwebsock_wait(ctx); then the program successfully begins listening on the socket 8888, but does not fire up the websocket. Any ideas on how I can counteract this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The point of the `accept` call is to block and wait for incoming connections.  So `runsocket2()` is never called and `runsocket()` "freezes" as it should. You could set the socket to non-blocking using `socket(AF_INET|SOCK_NONBLOCK, SOCK_STREAM, 0)` but you'd still have to continuously check for an incoming connection.  You could create the socket and use the `select` statement. (See the man pages). Or the best way to go is thread `runsocket()`

Comment: Will threading it allow me to run the second instance without halting the program??

Comment: @JonnyWhatshisface That's a bit like asking if `while` statements will allow you to write loops. I suggest reading up on threads if you're lacking such a basic understanding of them. The whole point of threads is to allow multiple independent flows of control within a single address space, so ... yes, threading will allow that.